Characteristic equation and eigensystem yield different results
I am comparing the eigenvalues one obtains with Eigensystem of a matrix $\Omega$ and by solving the characteristic equation for the same matrix, but when I do so I get different results: what am I not understanding?
\[CapitalOmega] = ( {
    {0, 1/m, Subscript[\[Omega], B], 0},
    {-m Subscript[\[Omega], 1]^2, 0, 0, Subscript[\[Omega], B]},
    {-Subscript[\[Omega], B], 0, 0, 1/m},
    {0, -Subscript[\[Omega], B], -m Subscript[\[Omega], 2]^2, 0}
   } );
eigvals = Eigensystem[Transpose[\[CapitalOmega]]][[1]];
Solve[Det[
   Transpose[\[CapitalOmega]] - \[Lambda] IdentityMatrix[4]] == 
  0, \[Lambda]]

(Note that in the example I do this for the transpose of $\Omega$ as I need to work with the left eigenvectors of this matrix)

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! They are in fact the same solutions, you can cancel $m$ in the fractions of eigvals: FullSimplify[eigvals == sol[[All, 1, 2]], m > 0], where sol = Solve[Det[...]].

right, thank you I thought I was going crazy. If you post the answer I will cred it it to you

I've voted to close the question, since it is rather trivial mistake :)

Simplify[eigvals == (\[Lambda] /. t) , m > 0] will do the trick.

where t=Solve[Det[    Transpose[\[CapitalOmega]] - \[Lambda] IdentityMatrix[4]] ==    0, \[Lambda]]
